# Conversion from BsonDouble list to double[] java

Tags: java, mongodb, java-8, bson

I need to convert an ArrayList of BsonDouble to double[]. The code below throws the exception:

> 'java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Double cannot be cast to org.bson.BsonDouble'

```
 List<BsonDouble> bsonDoubles =
       (List<BsonDouble>) doc.get(entry.getKey());

 double[] d = 
    bsonDoubles.stream().mapToDouble(BsonDouble::doubleValue).toArray();
```

Where doc is a BSON Document object and entry.getKey() returns a String that fetches the document field. 
From the exception it seems like I am casting the wrong direction, but it seems correct to me. Help appreciated.

I am using:

- compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver', version: '3.8.0'
- compile group: 'org.mongodb', name: 'mongodb-driver-reactivestreams', version: '1.9.2'
- java-jdk1.8

Comment: please share `doc.get(entry.getKey())` all the initialisations of the attributes here..like what is currently the value of `doc`, what is `entry` (map constructed of)?

Comment: @nullpointer entry.getKey() is a String. Just found the problem  - the document actually contained List<Doubles> and not BsonDoubles. The values were inserted as List<BsonDouble> but perhaps the driven converts these... anyways sorry for the trouble. The code executes correctly when bsonDoubles is changed to List<Double>.

Answer (score 0):

There was a wrong assumption about the datatype being returned. The code below will execute fine:

```
List<Double> bsonDoubles = (List<Double>) doc.get(entry.getKey());
double[] d = bsonDoubles.stream().mapToDouble(Double::doubleValue).toArray();
```